# Hosting non-profit application using Docker container

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, hosting, web-hosting

I've been developing a web application for a very amazing charity for the past two months. I have a Docker image, container, repository etc. and want to publish my web app for the public to see and interact with. It is a UK/Ireland based charity.

The problem is that hosting seems to be quite expensive. Is there any discounted/free hosting services available for non-profits to host their applications? I've seen some for US Charities. Are there any services providing a discount which would be able to host my Docker container? Right now it is sitting on the free version of Heroku, which is definitely not suitable for a lot of traffic.

(Also, I'm new to hosting/Docker so any tips/first steps would be well appreciated!)

Comment: This question will probably be closed due to its off-topicness, but for your needs, seems like DigitalOcean is a good option. It is cheap, and beginner friendly - and perhaps even have something for non profit. Good luck.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to find someone who owns a server and let him host your project. Google Cloud has a free tier for user with verified CC. Same for Heroku but at Google Cloud you get a VPS where you have more control over. AWS offers something similar. Digital Ocean costs 5€ a month but as a student you can get the GitHub Education pack giving you 50€ store credit. There are some VPS providers like Vultr where you can rent a VPS for 2.5€ a month. If your connection is stable you can get a Raspberry Pi. You can add a donate button to your project to finance it.

Answer (score 1):

Azure has an excellent grant plan for verified NPOs you can use for anything (we are using it).

Azure isn't the most user-friendly, but it's probably worth the effort to get to know it.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Web Services provides a grant of $1000 per year](https://www.techsoup.org/support/articles-and-how-tos/aws-nonprofit-credit-program-faq), but you have to pay a $95 admin fee.

> AWS, through TechSoup, will make one grant of $1,000 in credits per fiscal year (July 1 to June 30) to eligible 501(c)(3) organizations. Organizations can apply these service credits toward usage fees for all AWS on-demand cloud services, as available by region. AWS credits are not valid for Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances, Amazon Mechanical Turk, AWS Marketplace, Amazon Route53 domain name registration or transfer, or any upfront fee for any service. They are available for monthly support fees.